# is it possible to change the font of menu in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I'm using tkinter in python then I changed the font of file menu bar in tkiner but just changed somethings inside of file not the "File" I want to changed the font of "File", "Edit" and "Help" in my code not what is inside of them.

```
from tkinter import *

def donothing():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)
   button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
   button.pack()

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0,activeborderwidth=4,activeforeground='red2',fg='blue',bg='thistle4',font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0,activeborderwidth=4,activeforeground='red2',fg='blue',bg='thistle4',font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))

editmenu.add_separator()

editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
editmenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
editmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))

menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0,activeborderwidth=4,activeforeground='red2',fg='blue',bg='thistle4',font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=donothing,font=('Franklin Gothic Demi Cond', 11))
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The menubar is a native component, under control of the underlying OS. I don't think it's possible for tkinter to change the font of the menubar.